# Non-deterministic logarithmic time complexity class

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, nondeterminism

Is that true that $Time(O(log(n)))=NTime(O(log(n)))$ iff $P=NP$?
It seems to me to be true, as I only need to take log on both sides, since log of a polynomial is $O(\log(n))$, but I don't know how to derive a proof from this intuition.

Comment: You can try using the technique of *padding*.

Comment: OK, this gives me one direction (lhs implies rhs). How about the second direction?

Comment: Only one direction of such implications is known.

Comment: Could you please supply me with some citation or a source?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific citation to this effect.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Aren't sublinear time classes decidable in constant time, so the left hand side is true unconditionally?

Comment: @Ariel This sounds reasonable for the Turing machine model.

Comment: @DudiFrid If you're talking about query complexity (you can ask the i'th bit of the input), I suggest you include it in the question. Otherwise, see my previous comment.

Comment: What computation model are you interested in? Turing machine? Random-access machine?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathsf{DLOGTIME\subsetneq NLOGTIME}$. Search in unsorted array is a problem from $\mathsf{NLOGTIME}$, but it can't be solved deterministically in logarithmic time. This is proven. I also think that $\mathsf{NLOGTIME\not\subset DTIME}(o(n))$.

Padding argument here do not have an implication for $\mathsf P$ vs. $\mathsf{NP}$.